# Install jQuery image slider in ASP.NET page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to install this image slider in a page that uses a master page:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/jquery-image-slider-in-Asp-Net/
In this example, he uses a page without using master page, so i create new page (this time not using master page) and worked fine.

this is what my code ends up in the master page based page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
        <script src="Scripts2/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts2/Demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
   //some content here
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="nivo-slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="4.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#nivo-slider').nivoSlider();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

the code above not working!
on the other hand, this code working fine:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>        
    <script src="Scripts2/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts2/Demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="nivo-slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="4.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#nivo-slider').nivoSlider();
        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See your browser developer console, there must be some sort of `undefined` error.

Comment: Try with keeping scripts and links in Content2.

Comment: @suman pathak wow, it works now! thanks very much
but why it didn't work while in Content1? shouldn't this represent the head tag?

Comment: @MohammedElshawaf Maybe you have something wrong in your master page. I tried the code you mentioned not working for you with master page like:

Comment: Does two scripts folders (one named 'scripts' and the other named 'scripts2') cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried the code you mentioned not working for you with a master page and it works fine for me. Maybe you have something wrong in your master page. Here is the complete code that works fine for me.

### Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestUpdatePanel.Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts2/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts2/Demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="nivo-slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="4.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#nivo-slider').nivoSlider();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

### MasterPage.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="TestUpdatePanel.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```